# sap.m.Table removeColumn does not delete the corresponding items

Tags: sapui5

If I remove one Column using a `sap.m.Table` from a standard view the corresponding items are still available. The problem here is that the ordering is wrong after I delete a column here. [image: sap.m.Table]

Lets say I want to delete the "Historie"-Column, the corresponding items are still available. How can I delete one column with the items of one column here?

The problem here looks like that:

[image]

As you can see in the picture below I have deleted some columns and also the "Historie"-Column. The corresponding items are still available.
How to solve this and delete the matching items here using `sap.m.Table`?

I tried to remove the Columns by `removeColumn(oCol)` from the API: [sap.m.Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.42.8/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Table.html)

Comment: If you are talking regarding how to delete the whole item on click of `Historie` link. Then on click of `Historie` link then get the item using `oEvent.getSource().getParent()` and delete the table items using `oTable.removeItem(oEvent.getSource().getParent())`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I don't want to delete just one row. I want to delete all rows corresponding to deleted column using table.removeColumn()

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug with sap.m.Table.

For your problem, you can use the visible property of column to hide the column from view. Though it will not remove the column from the table.

```
    var oTable = this.byId('idTable');
    var oDeleteColumn = oTable.getColumns()[0]; //fetch the column you want to hide
    oDeleteColumn.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: That won't work, because I also want to reorder the columns and the same issue will occur then.

Answer (score 0):

`removeColumn()` removes the column only from the table's `<column>` aggregation, but not from the data.

If it is an option for you, than use [Table Personalization](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/overview-table-personalization/):

> Table personalization can be used to modify the display and settings
>   of a table.
>
> It is a UI pattern that is used to change one or more of the following
>   attributes:
>
> - **Visibility of columns**
> - Order of columns
> - Sorting
> - Grouping
> - Filtering

[Sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.50.10/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TablePerso/preview)